# Unable to run a simple C program on VS Code

Tags: windows, gcc

I follow the below link to setup VS Code environment for C programming (C++\GCC on Windows)
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

On the Step 8 testing，
gcc --version (OK - I got the version info.)
g++ --version (OK - I got the version info)
gdb --version (Failed - I got the message "It is not inner or outer command, executable program, or batch file")

I try to compiler/run a small program while I got the error shown on the image.

[Running] cd "c:\Users\Kevin Chen\Documents\C Language" && gcc 0104.c -o 0104 && "c:\Users\Kevin Chen\Documents\C Language"0104
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crtexewin.o): in function `main': C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:67:(.text.startup+0xbd): undefined reference to` WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.122 seconds

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No [tag:compiler-construction] here. Don’t use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Undefined Reference to WinMain Error:**

This error indicates that the linker is expecting a function named WinMain as the entry point, which is typically used for Windows GUI applications. However, you're likely trying to compile a console application, which uses main as the entry point.
Solution:
Ensure your code has a main function defined, not WinMain.
If you're accidentally compiling for a GUI application, add the -Wl,-subsystem,console flag to the compiler command to explicitly specify a console subsystem.

**2. Missing gdb:**

Cause: gdb (GNU Debugger) might not have been installed or its path is not configured correctly in VS Code.
Solution:
Reinstall MinGW: If you're unsure, reinstall MinGW, making sure to select gdb during installation.

Configure Path in VS Code:
Go to File > Preferences > Settings (or press Ctrl+,).

Search for "terminal.integrated.env.windows" and add the path to gdb's bin directory (e.g., C:\msys64\mingw64\bin) to the list.

**Additional:**

Save Code Before Compilation: Save your 0104.c file before running the compilation command.
Check File Paths: Double-check the file paths in your compilation command for any typos.
Reinstall MinGW: If issues persist, consider reinstalling MinGW to ensure a clean setup.

Comment: May I know what is the correct VS Code environment install and setup for Language C development?  Thanks.

Comment: I feel I may follow the incorrect instructions. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I found the issue is existed on my source code, after fixed the code, I am able to complier and run C program successfully.   Thanks.